# bootstrap col-xl-6 not working properly that is remaining portion don't print anything

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

when use the code col-xl-6 the remaining portion stays blank and next content displays in the next raw. what is the problem?

```
<div class="raw">
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a gal</p>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a gal</p>
 </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*row* is the proper class not *raw*.

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
   <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a gal</p>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a gal</p>
 </div>

    </div>
```